# Find the Image $2x-3y=0$ given matrix transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Be $M$ the linear transformation represented by matrix $T$:

$$T = 
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    5 & 2 \\
    4 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]
$$

Mark the correct answer which show the image by $M$ of the line $2x-3y = 0$

(A) $19x - 8y = 0$

**(B) $19x - 14y = 0$** (answer)

(C) $19x -15y = 0$

(D) $15x-14y = 0$

(E) $4x - 5y = 0$

Any hints?

My first attempt was related the tranformation the each coordanaties from line r: 2x-3y = 0 with matrix T.

r as a vector: $\vec{r} = \left[\begin{matrix} 2\\-3\end{matrix}\right]$

$\vec{z} = T . \vec{r} =  \left[\begin{matrix} 4\\-5\end{matrix}\right]$ (wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $2x-3y=0$ defines a subspace. The vector $r$ that you used is orthogonal to this line.

The correct point of view is to look at the line as set of all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $(x,y)=(x, \frac{2}{3}x)$ since $y=\frac{2}{3}x$. So it suffices to check where $T$ sends, say $(3,2)$ (which is on the line). Thus, computing
$\begin{pmatrix} 5& 2\\ 4& 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$
should give the answer.

Comment: misunderstand with some concepts but got that point. Thank you anyway

Comment: You should at least accept this as an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to obtain the image of the given line

$$2x-3y = 0$$

is to obtain images *of its $2$ points* - why don't select the natural points $A=[0,0],\ B=[3,2]$?

Computing their images we obtain

$$\left( \begin{matrix}
    5 & 2 \\
    4 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right )\cdot
\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ) = \color{red}{
\left( \begin{matrix}
    0\\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right )},\quad\left( \begin{matrix}
    5 & 2 \\
    4 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right )\cdot
\left( \begin{matrix}
    3 \\
    2 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ) = \color{red}{
\left( \begin{matrix}
    19\\
    14 \\
    \end{matrix}\right )},$$

Now we write the equation of the line passing through resulting points $\color{red}{(0, 0)}$ and $\color{red}{(19, 14)}$, obtaining the **correct** result

$$\color{red}{14x-19y=0},$$

which is *similar* to your **incorrect** result (B).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of the problem this way: If you’ve been given some equations that describe the relationship between the pairs of variables $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$, how might you express the equation $2x-3y=0$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$? One way is to solve those first equations for $x$ and $y$, then substitute into $2x-3y$ and simplify. In this case, you’re given that $$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = T \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},\tag1$$ so solving for $x$ and $y$ is a simple matter of computing $T^{-1}$.

You could also work directly with vectors and matrices. The equation of the line can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = 0\tag2$$ (verify this). Substituting from (1) for $[x,y]^T$, this becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-3\end{bmatrix}T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = 0\tag3,$$ so the coefficients of the transformed equation are the elements of the row vector $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}5&2\\4&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$ I trust that you’re able to compute the value of this expression at this stage of your studies.

Incidentally, the vector $[2,-3]^T$ is orthogonal (normal) to the line. Equation (3) shows that such normal vectors transform differently than do vectors that represent points: If the point transformation is given by $\mathbf v' = M\mathbf v$, then a normal vector $\mathbf n$ transforms as $\mathbf n' = M^{-T}\mathbf n$. (The $-T$ superscript means “inverse transpose.”)

Comment: But $T$ might not be invertible everytime.

Comment: @chhro That’s no different from not being able to solve for $x$ and $y$ in the first paragraph. In that case, you have to use another method. Happily, $T^{-1}$ exists in the specific instance. It wasn’t my intent to provide a comprehensive answer replete with obfuscating details. One could quibble that the given line might not pass through the origin, in which case the method in your answer doesn’t quite apply.

Comment: Very interesting approach @amd . Ty for take your time to add more details and rich information. :)

Comment: I'm sure my argument works even if the given line is not a subspace since it is independent of the given linear transformation $T$. It's essentially the idea in MarianD's answer.

Comment: @chhro You’re tacitly taking advantage of the fact that $T(0)=0$. When the line isn’t a subspace, it does _not_ suffice to check where $T$ sends a single point on the line.

Comment: Of course it does. $T$ is a linear transformation. The point on the line is interpreted as a vector in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @chhro You need the images of _two_ points on a line, not one, to determine its image. In your answer, you’re implicitly taking advantage of the fact that if the line passes through the origin, then because $T$ is a linear transformation, so does its image.

Comment: Okay you win.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1.** Realize that $\{《x, y》: 2x + 3y = 0\}$ is a subspace.

**STEP 2.** find the basis for the subspace. It is $(1, 2/3)$.

**STEP 3.** Do matrix multiplication.

$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
    5 & 2 \\
    4 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    2/3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ] =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
    19/3\\
    14/3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]$$

**STEP 4.** Translate back into equation form.

$$P_1 = \alpha \left[ \begin{matrix}
    19/3 \\
    4/3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]$$ and $$P_2 = \beta \left[ \begin{matrix}
    19/3 \\
    4/3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right ]$$. Plug these two points (interpreting the top entries as x coordinate and bottom entries as y-coordinate). Use the point-slope equation $$y = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2 - x_1}x$$.

Comment: y2 is the y-coordinate of P2. x2 is the x-coordinate of P2. y1 is the y-coordinate of P1. x1 is the x-coordinate of P1.